# Python patten for progress count

Tags: python

I often have to run lot of maintenance scripts, I always insert below code to track the progress of any iterable.

```
c = len(sequence)
i = 1
for s in sequence:
    print "{}/{}".format(i,c)
    i+=1
    # Do something
```

Are there more elegant & pythonic ways to convert this code as a reusable patten?

Comment: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)  (I am actively writing a more complete answer)

Comment: Aww, Any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a word: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, s in enumerate(sequence):
    print "{}/{}".format(i,c)
    #do stuff
```

To signal progression out of the total however you will prabably want to `start` at 1 (enumerate takes `start=1` as an argument)

Although if you also find yourself using that exact print statement frequently you can wrap this in a generator.

```
def verbose_enuemrate(seq):
    total = len(seq)
    #print "starting verbose_enumerate with:", seq
    for i,item in enumerate(seq, start=1):
        print("{}/{}".format(i,total))
        yield i,item
    #print "finished verbose_enumerate of:", seq

>>> for i,c in verbose_enuemrate("abc"):
    print(c)    
1/3
a
2/3
b
3/3
c
```

Comment: I took this, And changed the `yield` just to return the `item`, As I am won't use it index anyway :) And started calling `verbose_enuemrate` as `track`, Just feels like a decorator  :)

Comment: In that case you may want to call it something other then `verbose_enumerate`,  maybe `show_progression` or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code to show progress on the same line.

```
import time
print "Work in progress(0%%)", # Python 2 print without newline
for work_done in range(10):
    print "\b\b\b\b\b%2d%%)" % work_done, # Backspace then overwrite
    time.sleep(1) # or do some work
```

Comment: The OP wants to make the code easier to write/re-use, not improve the user display.

Comment: I missed the "maintenance" part when I first commented, I thought that printing the iteration was for debugging but seeing how I was wrong, this is very good advice!